# Как составить формулу для определения вектора смещения одной материальной точки под воздействием силы притяжения другой?

Tags: разработка-игр, физика

Помогите составить формулу, по которой бы определялся вектор смещения одной материальной точки *(me)* под воздействием силы притяжения другой *(planet):*

```
var me = {
    x: 0,  // положение в пространстве
    y: 0,
    vx: 0,  // вектор смещения
    vy: 0,
    radius: 1,  // радиус (нужен для расчета массы и при визуализации)
    mass: Math.PI * 1 * 1 // масса = 3.14
    };

var planet = {
    x: 2000,
    y: 2000,
    radius: 500,
    mass: Math.PI * 500 * 500 // 785398.16
    };

function step()
{
me.vx = ?
me.vy = ?

me.x += me.vx;
me.y += me.vy;
}
```

Да, пренебрегать планетой нехорошо, особенно при такой небольшой разнице в размерах, но для «геймплея» важно, чтобы планета была статична. Поэтому применять смещение я буду только к *me*.

Кроме того, хочу спросить, как по-вашему, верно ли хранить вектор смещения таким образом или лучше хранить угол и скорость. Это позже тоже может оказаться очень важным. Позже — это когда я буду задавать вам вопрос о том, как вывести тело *me* на орбиту *planet*. Но надеюсь, что меня подтолкнет на самостоятельный подбор формулы ответ на текущий вопрос.

Comment: при нулевых скоростях они упадут друг на друга по вектору направленному через центры масс. лучше хранить вектор скорости. и это - при использовании топлива для ускорения - масса падает, лучше это тоже учитывать.

Comment: «Они»? Не, планеты друг с другом не взаимодействуют. А за напоминание про топливо спасибо. Хотя, у меня все-равно все тела из одного вещества (включая корабль; то есть, плотность всех тел равна), поэтому, согласно Ньютону это никак не повлияет на ускорение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изменение скорости равно ускорению, умноженному на ваш квант времени (условное время вашей вселенной, через которое вы пересчитываете координаты).

Ускорение равно силе, делённой на массу.

Сила считается по закону всемирного тяготения:

```
F = G * m1 * m2 / r^2.
```

Тут `G` — гравитационная постоянная вашей вселенной, `m1`, `m2` — масса объекта и планеты, `r` — расстояние между ними. Вектор силы направлен вдоль линии, соединяющей планеты (не забудьте нормировать вектор, соединяющий центр планеты и объект).

Я в подобных случаях завожу отдельные типы для точки, вектора, вектора скорости и вектора ускорения, промежутка времени, а также операции над ними (точка минус точка даёт вектор, ускорение умножить на время даёт скорость и т. п.). Как представлены данные внутри классов — как декартовы координаты, направление и длина и ещё как-то, — внутреннее дело класса, может быть изменено в любой момент.

Не знаю, насколько подобная практика распространена в нетипизированном по стилю javascript (вы же на нём пишете, да?).

Comment: Ага, на нем, извращаюсь.
Моя основная проблема в том, что я не очень дружу с динамикой.
Пытался и раньше подобрать формулы, но все как-то не срасталось. Этой, конечно, тоже пользовался. Шел по вашим наводкам, но все-равно застрял. Получилось вот что:

<pre>
function step()
{
distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(planet.x - me.x, 2) + Math.pow(planet.y - me.y, 2));
    
f = game.G * me.mass * planet.mass / (distance * distance);
a = f / this.mass;

me.vx = (planet.x - me.x) * a;  // что-то не то...
me.vx = (planet.y - me.y) * a;

me.x += gx;
me.y += gy;
}
</pre>

Что-то не так.

Comment: @Bars: Ускорение — это вектор, его длину мы нашли (это `a`), надо найти и направление. Ускорение направлено вдоль линии силы, т. е. прямо к планете:

    var dirx = planet.x - me.x;
    var diry = planet.y - me.y;
    var distance2 = dirx * dirx + diry * diry;
    var distance = Math.sqrt(distance2);
    // лучше умножить, pow реально медленная фигня
    
    dirx /= distance;
    diry /= distance;
    // теперь (dirx, diry) -- единичный вектор

    var a = game.G * planet.mass / distance2;
    // сэкономили умножение и деление на me.mass

    var ax = dirx * a;
    var ay = diry * a;

Comment: @Bars: (продолжение)

    me.x += me.vx * game.deltaT;
    me.y += me.vy * game.deltaT;

    me.vx += ax * game.deltaT;
    me.vy += ay * game.deltaT;

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает. Хотя, не так как ожидалось, в таких масштабах приближение к реальности — некрасиво. Ну или, может, нужно просто поиграть с параметрами.

А для чего, позвольте спросить, еще множить на `deltaT` (квант времени?), ведь положение объекта меняется на каждом шаге.

Comment: @Bars: Ну, в основном для сохранения размерности, чтобы величины имели физический смысл, так легче следить за их правильностью. Эта величина задаёт, сколько времени проходит в вашей вселенной за один шаг. Ну и например, вы можете сделать симуляцию более точной, если уменьшите квант времени, и будете за секунду выводить больше шагов. Квант можно подгонять под производительность клиентской машины. И т. д.

Comment: Значение deltaT важно, т.к. me.vx += ax * game.deltaT дает не плавное увеличение скорости, а "ступеньки". Это соответствует численному интегрированию методом левых прямоугольников. Чем меньше deltaT, тем меньше будет ошибка. Для больших масштабов (Солнечная система, к примеру) и если не очень важна точность может быть достаточно кванта времени равного нескольким суткам.

Comment: @insolor, а да не, у меня все не так сложно, точность тут не нужна. Зато deltaT ∈ [0.1, 0.9] может пригодиться для реализации bullettime :)